# "tile" option is missing in Gnome Teaks / Background / Appearance / Adjustment in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, desktop-background, gnome-tweaks

"tile" option is missing in Gnome Teaks / Background / Appearance / Adjustment in Ubuntu 22.04. Is it a bug or is it intended this way?

Comment: Sorry, I formulated the question incorrectly.

In previous versions, (e.g., in 20.04), the "wallpaper" option would tile the screen with an image. In 22.04, the "wallpaper" option is still present, but it now acts differently, it just scales the image but does not tile it. So I guess this is probably a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Possible options for the setting `org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options` include “none”, “wallpaper”, “centered”, “scaled”, “stretched”, “Zoom”, “spanned”. You can see that for yourself with the command `gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options`.

"Tile" is not an option, so it would make no sense of the developpers of Gnome Tweaks added it. So, likely, this is not a bug and is intended this way.